# Passing Authentication Key in header but access denied 401 in JMeter in Rest API Load Testing

Tags: jmeter

Request

POST http://18.185.139.167:8080/dashboard/customer/search

POST data:

```
{
  "q":"",
  "pageNumber":0,
  "pageSize":1000,
  "sortBy":"createdDate",
  "sortDirection":"desc",
  "advertisementid":"web",
  "deviceid":"web,
  "devicetype":"web",
  "gcmorapnsid":"web",
  "source":"web"
 }
```

[no cookies]

**Request Headers:**

```
Connection: keep-alive  
Authorization: eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9JzdWIiOiJpb3RAdGF0YWNvbW11bmljYXRpb25zLmNvbSIsImF1ZGl lbmNlIjoid2ViIiwiY3JlYXRlZCI6MTUyMjczNjg5OTY2NCwiZXhwIjoxNTI1MTU2MDk5LCJqdGk iOiI1YTYxZjY4NmRhYzM2ODAyNTJkNjU5OGIifQ.O3SQuj4aEJdn--bv3T2j2r7cMKuNZPqCYlOG YsdPKu9vWOkJUgbvblntlycDJxpfZWPGh6R8GJ2CXkb  
Content-Type: application/json  
Content-Length: 188  
Host: 18.188.138.167:9009  
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.5 (Java/1.8.0_161)
```

**Response Data :**

```
{
  "timestamp" : 1522826733515,
  "status" : 401,
  "error" : "Unauthorized",
  "message" : "Unauthorized",
  "path" : "/dashboard/customer/search"
}
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @Nikit Kumar may I know how you passed the authentication key any image.